# How to get integer value and convert to string from enumeration?

Tags: c#

I have this class:

```
public class GameTypeModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string TransKey { get; set; }             
}
```

I have this foreach:

```
GameType.Add(new GameTypeModel() { Value = "", TransKey = "ALL" });
foreach (Game val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Game)))
{      
     GameType.Add(new GameTypeModel() { Value = value, TransKey = val.ToString() });
}
```

I have this enumeration:

```
public enum Game 
{
    [EnumMember]
    Terminal = 0, 
    [EnumMember]
    SportsBetting = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    LiveBetting = 2,
}
```

How can i use this numbers and pass it to Value like a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store "0", "1", "2" in `GameTypeModel.Value`, then just cast enum value to its [underlying type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) (it is `int` by default):

```
new GameTypeModel { Value = ((int)val).ToString(), TransKey = val.ToString() }
```

Comment: this is what i need :) tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
    Game item = Game.LiveBetting;
    String itemselected= Enum.GetName(typeof(Game), item);
```

Comment: how can i add that in foreach?

Comment: foreach ( int i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Game)))
            {
                Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(Game), i);
            }

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: `.ToString()`to get the value ?

Answer (score 0):

Easy thing mate. You'll have to cast the values to int before you convert them into string. Try this..

```
public enum Game : int {
    Terminal = 0,
    // ...
}

// add the explicit cast to int here
GameType.Add(
    new GameTypeModel() { 
        Value = value, 
        TransKey = ((int)val).ToString() 
    });
```